# how to use setter/getters during init()?

Tags: swift, init

I've never quite grasped what's going on with init().

Is there a clean, simple way to achieve what I'm trying to do in the code below ?

Edit: I'd like to avoid duplicating the `data = value / 2` logic, because it might be significantly more complex than this simple example.   I also don't want to provide a default value for `data` or make it optional because I want a compile-time guarantee that `data` is initialized.

```
fileprivate struct Foo {
    
    var data: Int
    
    var twiceAsMuch: Int {
        set(value) {
            data = value / 2
        }
        get {
            data * 2
        }
        
    }
    
    init(twice: Int) {
        // The following line won't compile because
        // "Self used before all stored properties are initialized"
        self.twiceAsMuch = twice
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but shouldn’t `data` be declared `private`? A simple solution to your problem is to initialize it with a value like zero first, either in the init or as part of the property declaration.

Comment: thanks for looking Joakim.  In this case, no, I want data public.  I also don't want give it a default value because I want to know at compile time that it's being initialized to a meaningful value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited. This method only works if the calculation does not depend on instance variables.

It's telling you that until "init" has executed, the struct state required for the computed variable is not initialized.

This compiles just fine: (I assumed you wished to divide the initial value inside the initializer.

```
    
fileprivate struct Foo {
    
    var data: Int
    static private func twiceAsMuch(_ v: Int) -> Int { v / 2 }
    var twiceAsMuch: Int {
        set(value) {
            data = Self.twiceAsMuch(value)
        }
        get {
            data * 2
        }
    }
    
    init(twice: Int) {
        self.data = Self.twiceAsMuch(twice)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'm hoping for approaches which don't duplicate the logic in my setter().

Comment: hi Ron - cheers, yes, that gets it done.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an [`init` accessor](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0400-init-accessors.md) to allow `self.twiceAsMuch = twice`. This is the accessor that will be called when you set a computed property in `init`.

`twiceAsMuch` would look like this:

```
var twiceAsMuch: Int {
    set(value) {
        data = value / 2
    }
    get {
        data * 2
    }
    
    @storageRestrictions(initializes: data)
    init(value) {
        data = value / 2
    }
}

// now this compiles!
init(twice: Int) {
    self.twiceAsMuch = twice
}
```

Note that you should indicate which stored properties the `init`er would initialise. In this case, it's `data`.

For your simple `Foo` struct this isn't any more convenient than directly doing `self.data = twice / 2`. But if you have multiple initialisers that all needs to set `twiceAsMuch`, and the computation is more complicated than a division by 2, you can avoid repeating the same computation.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this one, nice +1.

Comment: Thanks Sweeper. This is interesting and feels like it's going the direction I'd expect. But while I get that I'm avoiding some code duplication by having the business logic in an init accessor instead of directly in an init, the logic is still being duplicated once.  If the logic were more substantial I'd really like to avoid duplicating it even once.   Or if instead of a single property setter() I had something like "updateState(from:___)" which set a whole bunch of properties.

Comment: @orionelenzil You can always just write a [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) global function, that gives you the value to assign to `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization is the process of allocating memory for any instance, such as class/struct/enum. During this process, each stored property **must** be assigned an initial value before it's ready to use. Imagine how you can use an instance/variable without knowing where it is, it has to be somewhere in memory, and this 'somewhere' happens during the `init` function.

```swift
fileprivate struct Foo {
    var data: Int
}
```

By declaring above, you're saying that `Foo` has `data` that is stored later.
And computed property is nothing like a kind of `function`, it doesn't actually hold a value. It just provides a getter and a setter to communicate with other properties. Every single time computed properties get called, they will be calculated again. It may take O(1), O(n) or more time depending on the getter and setter. Instead of stored property, it is just a block of memory and it often costs O(1).

So, in short, you're 'communicating' with a memory that wasn't allocated. Then the solution is to 'feed' its instance some memory. There are a couple ways to do it:

1. Simply give a default value for these stored properties:

```swift
fileprivate struct Foo {
    var data: Int = 0
    ...
    init(count: Int) {
        self.doubleCount = count
    }
}
```

2. Declare as optional:

```swift
fileprivate struct Foo {
    var data: Int?
    ...
    init(count: Int) {
        self.doubleCount = count
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I guess I don't quite understand how the memory isn't allocated, if I can set `self.data` in the init, but can't call a function which sets `self.data`.

Comment: I don't want give it a default value or make it optional because I want to know at compile time that it's being initialized to a meaningful value.